# How to move from Special to General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

I have understood special relativity nicely, and right now I am trying to learn general relativity from D'Inverno's book. I an finding it rather difficult to understand the pre-requisite math (i.e. tensors) for general relativity. Please suggest some source from where I could learn the general relativity math, as if it's being taught to a kid.

Also note, that I have a 5 year undergraduate Degree in Geo-physics, so I believe I have a good enough background.

PS: Apology, if this is a duplicate question

Comment: I strongly recommend [A first course in general relativity](http://www.amazon.com/A-First-Course-General-Relativity/dp/0521277035/ref=sr_1_2) by Bernard Schutz. He introduces the maths in a nice gentle way. If you're comfortable with basic calculus you should be fine.

Comment: @JohnRennie Started reading it. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Good :-) It was the first GR book I found that I could actually understand!

Answer (score 1):

It has been nearly a decade since this question was posed, so I doubt my answer will do OP any good, but for those who come across this question now:

The above recommendation of "A first course in general relativity" by Schutz is good. I really don't have much to say about it, but it's a strong introduction.

Personally, though, I would recommend "A general relativity workbook" by Moore. Moore does an excellent job of walking you through an introduction to tensors and all of the underworkings of general relativity before actually getting into the theory itself. He also provides some of the best practice problems I've seen in any general relativity text.

For lighter reading on the topic that still gives good mathematical detail, I recommend "General Relativity" from the theoretical minimum series by Susskind. This was more recently published, and stands to the same writing standards of Susskind's other books.